# Are there side effects to adding new content to a Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, rest

I want to add a new object to an existing MongoDB document which I don't control and I don't want to break the vendors application. I've tried this in test code and it works fine, but I wanted some confirmation.

I'm using a RestAPI to drive a commercial product and under the hood the application is using MongoDB to persist. I can add new and arbitrary fields/objects to the JSon messages and they're persisted into Mongo as expected. Am I right that as long as my naming is different from existing/new vendor fields, then the Vendors application should just keep working, ignoring my new data?

Bonus points if there's an article covering this that I can reference.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB does not have a fixed schema and it treats all documents in a collection differently. With the new storage engine WiredTiger, even there is a document level transaction. So adding a new document to the existing collection should not matter most. However, if you are going to read that new document and its not indexed then reading time will be high